# Is it possible to calculate a moving average / EMA / windowed aggregate over a time series in RavenDb 5+?

Tags: indexing, mapreduce, time-series, ravendb, moving-average

RavenDb 5+ adds support for timeseries storage against documents. Included in this support is indexing, although in order to create storage and indexing performance benefits, indexing is done in batches of TimeSeriesSegments.

RavenDb includes support for calculating basic Count/Avg/Sum aggregates on these TimeSeries in totality. However, I can't find a way to calculate a *moving* average, over a window.

For example, I might have 50 days of values, one value per day. Using the built-in Avg, I can trivially index the average value across all 50 days. However, I'd like to create an index field which contains the moving average over a window of, say, 5 days. The first X-1 days' values would therefore be null/blank, and from that point onwards the average would be calculated over the preceding X days.

I can't find a trivial way to accomplish this in RavenDb's map/reduce indexing strategy, but I'm hoping I'm missing some clever way to (for example) run a query from within the Map operation in order to query for the previous values even though they might not fall within the current TimeSeriesSegment.

If it is possible, I'd also like to be able to take it further and calculate a compound of several of these moving averages - for example, the *exponential moving average* of a value over time.

This is an *ideal* operation for an index, since the data doesn't change after being written, but I don't know if there is windowing / cursor-style support when defining a RavenDb index.

I could achieve this using triggers etc in a SQL-like store instead of RavenDb, but if possible I'd prefer not to get into having some code stored in sprocs and some within my C# codebase.

TYIA!

Comment: Timeseries indexing:
https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/5.1/csharp/document-extensions/timeseries/indexing
+ Query an index:

https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/5.1/csharp/document-extensions/timeseries/querying/using-indexes

Comment: @Danielle thank you but that doesn't clarify if it's possible to create an index containing a value calculated over a window of other (deterministic) values, such as in a moving average

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if there is a nicer way, but a map-reduce index should work.

Map:

```
from segment in timeseries.Companies.StockPrices
from entry in segment.Entries
let window = Enumerable.Range(0,5).Cast<object>()
from i in window
select new {
    Date = entry.Timestamp.AddDays((int)i),
    Value = entry.Values[0]*((double)1/(i+1)),
    Count = 1
}
```

Reduce:

```
from r in results
group r by r.Date into g
select new 
{
    Date = g.Key,
    Value = g.Average(x=>x.Value),
    Count = g.Sum(x=>x.Count)
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply! I'm not quite seeing how I would get `timeseries` to resolve to have `Companies` as a property (I'm in C# and inheriting from AbstractTimeSeriesIndexCreationTask<T, TResult>) - I had been using LoadDocument<T> to get at children. But I'll figure that out! My main question is - can this map operation see beyond the timeseries segment boundary in RavenDb? I had thought this was impossible, but I'll be excited to be wrong!

Comment: You can try to define this index on the http://live-test.ravendb.net/ with the sample data.

the `timeseries.Companies.StockPrices` is a naming convention to tell the index to work on the time-series data of the `Companies` collection that has the time-series `StockPrices`

If you need to index for each company individually, you should map the `segment.DocumentId` and reduce by it as well.  

What do you mean by `segment boundary`? here the index is iterating over each entry within the segment (`from entry in segment.Entries`)

Comment: Thank you! I'll give that a try. I was reading this as Linq rather than a raw index definition. By segment boundary, I read that RavenDb timeseries indexes call Map only on a TimeSeriesSegment. Let's say I have 1 year of data, and RavenDb has split this into 500 segments. Will this method correctly calculate the moving average across all data, even if a window of time spans two TimeSeriesSegments? Maybe I'm misunderstanding

Comment: Segments are only an implementation detail of how raven store the time-series data.
One segment may contain about 2k-4k of single dimension data points (data point == entry).
In index the segments are exposed for performance sake, you can access the Min/Max/Avg of the segment itself and in some cases spare the need for iterating over the entries within that segment. 
Another thing to mention here is that raven will re-index the entire segment if any of the entries with that segment changed. 
Hope that make sense :-)